# How can I turn my code into an actual aplication for windows?

Tags: c, gtk, cygwin

I developed a program written in C language using Gtk+ 3 for visual interface, and to run it I always use the comand line (Im using cygwin), but I would like to know how can i make my program an aplication, witch can be installed in windows and function like any other aplication (launch it throught files explorer or even throught the desktop enviroment)?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you have written the code portable, you basically have two options.

- Install GTK on Windows. You can find instructions here: https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/
- Rewrite the whole application for Windows API. This is NOT trivial.

On top of that, use [windows installer](https://www.microsoft.com/sv-se/download/details.aspx?id=8483)